# Trouble with foreach in login form

Tags: c#

I have a sql data base with column for username and password.
I made login form which is asking the user to enter a valid username and password.

The check for a wrong entry already works but the check when the username password combination is ok fails.

```
namespace Kartice
{
public partial class Pass : Form
{

    Matjaz Matjaz = new Matjaz();
    public Pass()
    {
       // string myconnection = @"C:\Users\Bojan\Desktop\Programiranje\School\Kartice\Kartice\Users.mdf";
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void usersBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Validate();
        this.usersBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.usersDataSet);

    }

    private void Pass_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'usersDataSet.Users' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.usersTableAdapter.Fill(this.usersDataSet.Users);

    }

    private void BtnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (Imetxt.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid user name!");
                Imetxt.Focus();
            }
            else if (Passtxt.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid password!");
                Passtxt.Focus();
            }

            string userName1, userPassword1;
            userName1 = Imetxt.Text;
            userPassword1 = Passtxt.Text;

            foreach (DataRow row in usersDataSet.Users)
            {
                if (row["Ime_Priimek"].ToString() == userName1)
                {
                    if (row["Password"].ToString() == userPassword1)
                    {
                        Pass myForm1 = new Pass();
                        Matjaz myForm2 = new Matjaz();

                        myForm2.Show();
                        myForm1.Hide();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("You have entered a wrong user name or the password!");
            }
}
```

Comment: You need to explain better what your problem is: in what way is your code not working?

Comment: @MillieSmith this is `C#`, using `==` is generally preferred.

Comment: For starters, your MessageBox is _inside_ your for each loop, meaning that if I enter the correct credentials but I am user 100 in your dataset, i will first get 99 times a messagesbox that tells me i entered the wrong credentials!

Comment: So much bad here :(  Plain-text passwords. Pulling everyone's account info down to an unsecured station. Trying to hide current login form by creating a new one.

Comment: I think you actually want `this.Hide()` rather than `Pass myForm1 = new Pass()` and `myForm1.Hide()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The `MessageBox` is *inside* the `for` loop.

Let's assume we have 5 users in the table.

Let's assume I entered `luke` for the username, and the correct password.

```
=======================
| Username | Password |
|- - - - - | - - - - -|
| matthew  |  *****   |
| mark     |  *****   |
| luke     |  *****   |
| john     |  *****   |
=======================
```

Username `luke` is third in this table.

Here is the what your program does, in plain-English:

```
<<start>>
Is 'matthew' equal to 'luke'?
- No! Display a message box.

Is 'mark' equal to 'luke'?
- No! Display a message box.

Is 'luke' equal to 'luke'?
- Yes!
  - Is '****' equal to '****'?
    - Yes! Show Form2 and hide Form1.
<<end>>
```

Hopefully, the problem is clear now. The first thing you need to do is move the `MessageBox` out of the `for` loop.

```
bool userFound = false;
foreach (DataRow row in usersDataSet.Users)
{
    if (row["Ime_Priimek"].ToString() == userName1)
    {
        if (row["Password"].ToString() == userPassword1)
        {
            userFound = true;
            Pass myForm1 = new Pass();
            Matjaz myForm2 = new Matjaz();

            myForm2.Show();
            myForm1.Hide();
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (!userFound)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have entered a wrong user name or the password!");
}
```

Comment: You could do away with the userfound variable and just return instead of break

Comment: tenx all for your help :)Randwhite I think you understand me, I have sql database called Users, where I have IDUsername, NameLastname and Password collums :) so the form and code must check if the username and pass are right, new form should be open. Sorry if my code is not perfect but I'm trying to learn on easy "programs" making. 

But I have put in to my form your code and still not working, I get wrong password please try again :( I think it's something bad with my connection string, what you think?

Comment: Sorry it is ok, my mistake... some how in database in properties are spaces after username and password as additional keys... Probably cuz I set varchar 20... now i have to set something else...

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring all the other problems with plaintext passwords and downloading the database to the client etc....

Your message box is inside the for loop, so every user that doesn't match will show the MessageBox....

Changing the for loop to

```
foreach (DataRow row in usersDataSet.Users)
{
  if (row["Ime_Priimek"].ToString() == userName1 && row["Password"].ToString() == userPassword1)
    {
      Pass myForm1 = new Pass(); // Don't think you need this.
      Matjaz myForm2 = new Matjaz();

      myForm2.Show();
      myForm1.Hide(); // shouldn't this be this.Hide();
      return;
    }
  }
}
MessageBox.Show("You have entered a wrong user name or the password!");
```

**UPDATE**

Inline with other comments/answers

To prevent the user check carrying on when either username or password is empty insert a return statement after each focus call. It won't make a difference to your existing problem the above code fixes that, but I think its closer to your intended execution. e.g.

```
        if (Imetxt.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid user name!");
            Imetxt.Focus();
            return;
        }
        else if (Passtxt.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid password!");
            Passtxt.Focus();
            return;
        }
```